# try catch y el mensaje de error que no aparece

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, jsp, servlets

Disculpen una pregunta rápido, dentro de lo que he estado preguntando se darán cuenta que he estado programando a través del método

```
try {
}
catch(Exception e){
}
```

Eso debido a que he estado jalando datos de bases de datos en jsp, recordarán que estoy usando `Connection`, `PreparedStatement` o `Statement`, dependiendo cual usan en su caso, y `ResultSet` pues con el `DriverManager` es como se llama a la base de datos como se observa a continuación

```
    Connection con = null;
                PreparedStatement pst = null;
                ResultSet rs = null;
                
                try{  
                    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                    con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/rhcontino?useTimeZone=true&serverTimezone=UTC&autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false", "root", "esmeraldapimentel");
                    pst = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM requisicion WHERE id='"+folio+"'");
                    rs = pst.executeQuery();
                    
                    while(rs.next()){ 
                    }
             }
catch(Exception e){}
```

Bueno aqui es donde surge mi duda, si yo quiero mandar un mensaje de error de que dicho dato de una base de datos ya no existe, ¿como le hago? Porque ya lo intenté con `catch` y cualquier `Exception`, al menos que no le haya atinado a la excepción correcta, pero hasta ahora nada, solo me puedo conformar con la página en blanco, el que pueda comentar con su ayuda se lo agradeceré mucho, que tengan buen día

Comment: Las clases que usas para los tipos de excepción heredan de unas clases padre. Toooooooooodas son hijas de Throwable, ya ahí comienzas a encontrar Exception, RuntimeException, ... Revisa la documentación. Luego podrás implementar una buena práctica que es usar excepciones que tú definas para propagar la info en esos escenarios donde debes informar de un estado anormal

Answer (score 1):

ya lo resolví, miren, dentro del try catch como les platiqué estaba `while(rs.next()){.....}`, bueno, lo sustituí por `if(rs.next(){....} else{` y a partir de aqui ya puse que efectivamente no existía dato alguno o incluso se puede poner otra base de datos y se refleja dentro del mismo jsp `}`

Miren chequen

```
    //Antes inicializamos la conexion, el statement, el resultset
    try{
    //La conexion, el PreparedStatement y el ResulSet con la conexión a través de //DriverManager
        if(rs.netx()){
        Y todo lo que resulte en rs.getString(n) o rs.getInt(n) etc
        }
        else{
               //Un mensaje de error o
               //Un ejemplo de otras database
                String idi = request.getParameter("id");

                Connection con3 = null;
                PreparedStatement pst3 = null;
    //                Statement st = null;
                ResultSet rs3 = null;
                    
                    try{  
                        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                        con3 = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/rhcontino?useTimeZone=true&serverTimezone=UTC&autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false", "root", "esmeraldapimentel");
    //                    st = con.createStatement();
                        pst3 = con3.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM acrerequi WHERE id='"+idi+"'"); //   ");  
    //                     rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM rhcontino");
                        rs3 = pst3.executeQuery();
                        
                        while(rs3.next()){
                           Lo que resulte como anteriormente en rs.getString(n)
                        }
                }catch(Exception e){}
     
           }
    }catch(Exception e){}
```